# Transparent JEditorPane in a JScrollPane over a background JPanel

Tags: java, swing, transparent, jeditorpane

If I move the JScrollPane so it is in front of and partially covering the JPanel, then the JEditorPane inside of the JScrollPane has paint issues. It does not properly re-paint the JPanel's background. So you end up with screen painting issues when you scroll.

I have tried the overlap using the following methods
- JScrollPane inside of JPanel
- JScrollPane partially covering JPanel using FreeLayout (NetBeans GUI Builder)
- JScrollPane partially covering JPanel using JLayeredPane

The JPanel has a solid background right now, but I will extend it to have a gradient as soon as I get solid background to work.

How can I get the JEditorPane to bring in the cropped background from the JPanel?

I am making it transparent using `jEditorPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))`

I tried using `setOpaque(false)` like you would do for a panel, but that just seems to put back a default background if you do it to JEditorPane.

> Original question by a co-worker:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364460/jframe-screen-paint-issues-when-using-transparency

The original question was not as well written and did not seem to bring good answers.

Responses to co-worker question
suggestions:

- "Try with setOpaque(false); instead of setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));"
  **did not solve the problem.**
- "try adding validate () after the pack()" **did not solve the problem.**
- "paint your background image on the JViewport" **would not work because the
  background needs to extend beyond the
  JScrollView and also spread behind
  other components**
- "modify the graphics composite in the UI delegate's paint()" **If this will solve the problem, I would like to know how to do it.**

Comment: -1, I'm sure I saw this posted yesterday. What happened to the other posting. People don't like spending time repeating suggestions that have already been made.

Comment: See my edit. I would have posted this information from the start, but I wanted to keep the question short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) class has code that attempts to make all component non-opaque so the background will show through.

Edit:

If you want to play with transparent background then you can check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation of the problem and a couple of solutions.

In this case the BackgroundPane is the easier solution.

Comment: It does not work. The background does not show through, and still get screen painting issues when using `jEditorPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))`.

Comment: It works fine for me. There is not need to play with transparent background colors. The logic actually makes 3 components non-opaque, the scrollpane, the viewport and the editor pane, so that the background of the panel can be painted properly.

Comment: Found it. co-worker was setting non opaque, but did not remove the background color. I failed to set non-opaque of the viewport. I did not realize that viewport was a separate element. We were using setViewportView which was generated by the GUI builder. Don't know why BackgroundPanel did not set it to opaque like you expected it to.

Comment: @George Bailey, actually it is your responsibiltiy to post code that demonstrates the problem. Its called a SSCCE (http://sscce.org
). Most of the time you will find simple mistakes like this when  you cut the code down to the bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry for the trouble.